# How to create a sub post?

Tags: posts, categories

I'm planning to create a TV Streaming site and I want to know how can I make sub posts under a post? I want to make subposts cause they'll act as a mirror post of the episode
this is a structure that I plan to use:

```
Series01 (Category)
    - Episode 1 (Post)
        - Mirror 01 (Post)
        - Mirror 02 (Post)
        - Mirror 03 (Post)
    - Episode 2 (Post)
        - Mirror 01 (Post)
        - Mirror 02 (Post)
        - Mirror 03 (Post)
    - Episode 3 (Post)
        - Mirror 01 (Post)
        - Mirror 02 (Post)
        - Mirror 03 (Post)

Series02 (Category)
    - Episode 1 (Post)
        - Mirror 01 (Post)
        - Mirror 02 (Post)
        - Mirror 03 (Post)
    - Episode 2 (Post)
        - Mirror 01 (Post)
        - Mirror 02 (Post)
        - Mirror 03 (Post)
    - Episode 3 (Post)
        - Mirror 01 (Post)
        - Mirror 02 (Post)
        - Mirror 03 (Post)
```

If you know a better way to structure this then do tell me. So how can I make subposts?

Comment: Why won't a hierarchical post type work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Custom Post Type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post%5fTypes) with hierarchical structure, which works same as Pages.